# AndroidManifest code line

Tags: android, google-maps

What does the protection level attribute mean in this line of code of AndroidManifest.xml file? please? 
here is the code:

```
    <permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The [permission documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel) explains the protectionLevel attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permission protection level is an indicator of the risk and rules associated with a particular permission.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestPermission_protectionLevel

Signature for example indicates that the permission will only be granted if the permission author and the application are signed with the same certificate. An example of this might be where you have two applications that share a common functionality which is secured with a custom permission. That permission could then be marked Signature which indicates to the runtime to only allow that permission to be used with your two signed applications.